# Javascript import typescript file before transpilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, commonjs

I'm trying to add typescript to existing javascript project.
So if I run tsc, I get same working project in build folder with no issues.

Now I want to start adding typescript files
If I add one, and try to import it in existing javascript file like this:

```
require('./myNewTypescriptFile.ts').initialize();
```

And try to transpile and run project, I get syntax errors which indicate, that my typescript file is being interpreted as javascript. Even though in my build folder I can see, that there is proper transpiled myNewTypescriptFile.js file.

If I change my require to

```
require('../build/myNewTypescriptFile').initialize();
```

Now even the new file seems to work, but I'm forced to use this strange path.
Is this how typescript migration is supposed to work or am I missing something?

**EDIT** This project is on nodejs and written using commonjs module syntax, so I can't use import in javascript file, unless I rewrite all imports on all files which is a no go at the moment.

I run project using npm start which calls:

```
"nodemon build/index.js"
```

Comment: Neither of those look correct. Why is the extension in the import. It can be one of two things. You don't have typescript compilation setup for your run script only the build script. OR You may need to use import syntax instead of require. Remember build and run are two seperate scripts.

Comment: @DanielDuong, I updated my answer. I use node with commonjs, that's why the 'require' syntax. After any changes I run 'tsc'  command and then 'npm start', which I assume is the build and run scripts you mentioned.